# react-select is removing the selected value while re-rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have created a component which has the react-select dropdowns - component A
I'm calling Component A from Component B by passing the props.
**Component A**

```
 <react-select 
           options={PropA}          
    </react-select >
    <react-select 
             options={PropA}           
    </react-select >
```

**Component B**

```
<div>                
{showComponentA ? <ComponentA PropA={propA}
 PropB={propB}> </ComponentA> : <></>}                
 </div>
```

showComponentA is a boolean state variable whose value keeps on changing on button click.
now whenever the state of showComponentA is changing the value selected in react-select is disappearing.

how can I keep the value in react-select and make it independent of showComponentA state change.